# How to separate date and time

Tags: r

I`m giving an input as "a <- [12/Dec/2014:05:45:10]" 
a is not a time-stamp so cannot use any time and date functions

Now I want the above variable to be split down into 2 parts as:-
date --> 12/Dec/2014
time --> 05:45:10

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `gsub` to create a space between the Date and Time and use that to create two columns with `read.table`

```
 read.table(text=gsub('^\\[([^:]+):(.*)+\\]', '\\1 \\2', a),
                    sep="", col.names=c('Date', 'Time'))
 #          Date     Time
 # 1 12/Dec/2014 05:45:10
```

Or you can use `lubridate` to convert it to a 'POSIXct' class

```
 library(lubridate)
 a1 <- dmy_hms(a)
 a1
 #[1] "2014-12-12 05:45:10 UTC"
```

If we need two columns with the specified format

```
 d1 <- data.frame(Date= format(a1, '%d/%m/%Y'), Time=format(a1, '%H:%M:%S'))
```

#### data

```
 a <- "[12/Dec/2014:05:45:10]"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
a <- "[12/Dec/2014:05:45:10]" 
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C") # depends on your local setting
as.POSIXlt(a, format = "[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S]")
```

**Explanation**

Depending on your local setting you need to change it such that the abbreviated month names can be read. Then you can use `as.POSIXlt` together with the format string to convert your string in a date.